# Merging polygons

Tags: qgis, clip, merge

I am trying to merge together two polygons to create a polygon of the whole UK.
However, I can't seem to select more than one polygon.
Also it seems to be random as to which polygon will be selected. It's not always the same polygon, but I can only ever select one polygon at any one time.

I have tried toggling the edit button but that doesn't work either.

(If someone has a shapefile of the UK I can use then I won't need to do this)

[image: screen shot of three polygons I have created and a shapefile of countries I downloaded from online]

Comment: "I can't seem to select more than one polygon": how are you selecting your polygons (what tool - or icon - are you using)? By the way, you might find interesting datasets on [data.gov.uk](https://data.gov.uk/data/search?theme-primary=Mapping&res_format=SHP).

Comment: You can also download shapefiles for the UK using [DIVA-GIS](http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata). Select `United Kingdom` as country and `Administrative areas` as subject.

Comment: Did you try select it with "select tool" and CTRL  button ?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please edit the title of your question to include enough information for future visitors to be able to find this thread when looking for the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could install the [Merge Shapes Plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/mergeshapes/) and then merge all polygon layers (Shapefiles) within an input directory:

[image]